# configure chooses the "wrong" libraries

Tags: build

I'm trying to build Emacs 26 from source but `make` fails

```
./temacs --batch  --load loadup bootstrap
./temacs: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I search for `libjpeg.so` I have

```
$ locate libjpeg.so
/home/boffi/Downloads/processing-3.3.5/java/lib/amd64/libjpeg.so
/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/lib/libjpeg.so
/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/lib/libjpeg.so.9
/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/lib/libjpeg.so.9.2.0
/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/pkgs/jpeg-9b-habf39ab_1/lib/libjpeg.so
/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/pkgs/jpeg-9b-habf39ab_1/lib/libjpeg.so.9
/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/pkgs/jpeg-9b-habf39ab_1/lib/libjpeg.so.9.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.2.0
```

and it seems to me that Emacs is not looking at the system libraries...

Grepping the output of configure I have another suspicious line

```
$ ./configure | grep miniconda
  Does Emacs use a png library?    yes -  L/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/lib -lpng16
```

My question is, how can I screen the libraries installed by the Anaconda Python Distribution for its own use, so that `./configure` does not mess with them?

Or, on the other hand, how can I have `temacs` and later Emacs find the library they expect to load?

Comment: I had to uninstall conda to get the compile to work.

Comment: @JustinThomas Uninstalling `conda` is a bit too much, have a look at the answers below. It suffices to temporarily change the `PATH` during the execution of `config...`

Comment: Deactivating conda before install is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs uses the "libpng-config" tool to locate PNG include files and libraries. So yes, if you have multiple versions installed you need to adjust PATH so that the one you want to be used, is. For other libraries, it's normally "pkg-config" that is consulted, for which there is the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable. If Anaconda provides a pkg-config, it probably prefers Anaconda packages, so again adjusting PATH is probably the right solution.

Comment: Ooops, in December I somehow missed your answer, but it exactly pinpoints the problem... ፨ `$ libpng-config  --ldflags →
-L/home/boffi/lib/miniconda3/lib -lpng16` — thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`

I had a look at `config.log` to see where `configure` mentioned the paths used by the Anaconda distribution and I found 3 references to `miniconda3` — 2 were related to the PNG libraries
and one to the `PATH` variable... of course the `bin` directory of the Anaconda distribution has to be prepended to `PATH`, hasn't it?

To be sure that was not a problem with my `PATH` I issued the command

```
$ PATH=/usr/bin:/bin ./configure 2>/dev/null | grep -qs miniconda || make
...
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/boffi/src/emacs-26.0.90'
$
```

I have now a way to shade private Anaconda libraries from the scrutiny of `configure`, I have an instance of Emacs 26 too and eventually I have the doubt that
`configure` had been too smart in deducing too much from my `PATH`.

---

ps I'm not going to approve my answer because it seems to me just a workaround,
I'm convinced that a better solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers fixed the problem but in my case I couldn't have `/usr/bin` before my conda path. This is because I'm using a cluster and I need specific tools with versions that I install in my conda. Putting `/usr/bin` in front prioritize those installed by admin before my own installs. Of cource I can then prepend another folder that contains symlinks pointing to the right versions (essentially everything inside `conda/bin` except for `libpng-config`) but that's lame and a lot of work.

What I did was simply install Emacs inside conda, install ligpng15, and it solved it.

### update as of 2020/03/09:

Alternatively, I also tried to locate the missing library and add it to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
~$ locate libjpeg
# showing the location of libjpeg. In my case it's inside my anaconda
# /home/user/app/anaconda2/lib/libjpeg.so.9
~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/app/anaconda2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
~$ emacs 
# launches fine
```